# Convert data stored in latin1 to utf-8

Tags: django, python-2.7, mysql-python

I want to convert a latin1 data to utf-8.

#### models.py

```
class old_product(models.Model):
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # This field is latin1

class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) # This field is utf-8
```

#### view.py

```
def index(request):
    old_products =  old_product.objects.all()
    for product in old_products:
            product_id = product.product_id
            names = product.product_description
            name =  names.decode('latin1').encode('utf-8')  
            c = product_name(id = product_id,name = name)
            c.save()
    return render_to_response('products/all_products.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here I am moving all the previous data from `old_product` table to another table `product`. First when I stored data in `old_product` table that was in `latin1` and now I want to convert to it `utf-8` and want to stored in `product` table.  This is how data gets stored in `old_product` table - `STONE  Ø­Ø¬Ø± (ctn80pcs)`

When I tried this `name =  names.decode('latin1')` and this `name =  names.decode('latin1').encode('utf-8')`,
I have got this error *'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-12: ordinal not in range(128).* How can I convert?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
name = names.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')
```

python supports iso-8859-1 which is equivalent to latin-1

**Here is my try:**

```
>>> latin = 'fides'.encode('iso-8859-1')
>>> latin
'fides'
>>> ucode = latin.decode('utf8')
>>> ucode
u'fides'
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer.But its showing the same error 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-12: ordinal not in range(128).@CrazyGeek

Comment: I tried at my side but not getting any error, see my updates in answer.

Comment: but again i got an error latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 6: ordinal not in range(256).When i try to convert this word "VASE Ù…Ø²Ø±ÙŠØ§ (ctn24pcs)" @CrazyGeek

Comment: When i run ""VASE Ù…Ø²Ø±ÙŠØ§ (ctn24pcs)".decode('utf8')" i got this output "u'VASE \xd9\u2026\xd8\xb2\xd8\xb1\xd9\u0160\xd8\xa7 (ctn24pcs)'" so is this you want?

Comment: No i want to get its unicode.For example unicode of "STONE  Ø­Ø¬Ø± (ctn80pcs)" is "STONE  حجر (ctn80pcs)".Thanks for your answer.@ CrazyGeek.

Comment: I have gone through this http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/python-unicode-and-unicodedecodeerror and i am sure it will be help full to you.